# how to use a git repository as a dependency and import the dependency

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

for the last day im struggling to use a git repository as a component.
i tried alot of approaches, and none of then worked when i type `npm i`

here is some approaches that i have tried:

[npm install from Git in a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187956/npm-install-from-git-in-a-specific-version),

[How to use private Github repo as npm dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency)

[Git repository to a dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078409/git-repository-to-a-dependency-in-package-json)

[Import component from a different repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933659/import-component-from-a-different-repo)

i created 2 rep in git hub:

[main project](https://github.com/IgorEstevao/main-project) => should consume the component

[chocolate component](https://github.com/IgorEstevao/test-component) => thats my component

every time i put this in my package.json (main project repo), i got that error:

```
"dependencies": {
   "test-component": "IgorEstevao/test-component#master", # try 1
   "test-component": "git://github.com/IgorEstevao/test-component.git#0.0.1", # try 2
   "test-component": "git://github.com/IgorEstevao/test-component.git", # try 3...
}
```

`npm ERR! premature close`

How i use chocolate component in main project?

keep in mind in the future booth repositories gonna be private, so i think i will need to use github api key to access?

Comment: Is that your actual "dependencies" JSON? Three entries with the same key and a trailing comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep all your files in the project root directory instead of wrapping them in `my-cool-component`.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have an error in your JSON. JSON does not allow trailing commas. This is very annoying.

Remove the last comma from your dependency object.

```
"dependencies": {
   "test-component": "IgorEstevao/test-component#master", # try 1
   "test-component": "git://github.com/IgorEstevao/test-component.git#0.0.1", # try 2
   "test-component": "git://github.com/IgorEstevao/test-component.git", # try 3...
}                                                                     ^
                                                                      |
                                                                      |
                                                                remove this
```

I'm not very familiar with NPM, but having three different values for the same key is unlikely to be valid.

---

If you wish to use a Github repository as an NPM dependency, [follow the Github instructions](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages) as well as the [NPM instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

> As of version 1.1.65, you can refer to GitHub urls as just “foo”: “user/foo-project”. Just as with git URLs, a commit-ish suffix can be included.

To depend on the master branch of the `IgorEstevao/test-component` repository...

```
"dependencies": {
  "test-component": "IgorEstevao/test-component#master"
}
```

No trailing comma.